# Extract Content of firts Index[0] in each array If I have one array and has several array in it

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have one Array that has three array in side it and want to extract content of index[1] in each array

```
Array(4) [Array(3), Array(3), Array(1), Array(1)]
length:4
[
0:Array(3) ["cfdb9868-0f69-5781-b1e4-793301280788", "127.0.0.1", "9146"]  // Extract content of Index[0]
1:Array(3) ["cfdb9868-0f69-5781-b1e4-793301280788", "127.0.0.1", "9146"]  // Extract content of Index[0]
2:Array(1) ["b32f4c08-8d53-5fed-8034-4bfb144dfe10"]  // Extract content of Index[0]
3:Array(1) ["b32f4c08-8d53-5fed-8034-4bfb144dfe10"]  // Extract content of Index[0]
]
```

in each line I want extract just first variable,This is my result :

```
let result = [
                ["cfdb9868-0f69-5781-b1e4-793301280788"],["cfdb9868-0f69-5781-b1e4-793301280788"],
                ["b32f4c08-8d53-5fed-8034-4bfb144dfe10"],["b32f4c08-8d53-5fed-8034-4bfb144dfe10"] 
             ]
```

I used slice and split for have just first one but give me error function

Comment: `arr.map(e => e.slice(0, 1));` or `arr.map(e => [e[0]]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple solution using `Array.prototype.map` property

```js
const input = [
  ["cfdb9868-0f69-5781-b1e4-793301280788", "127.0.0.1", "9146"],
  ["cfdb9868-0f69-5781-b1e4-793301280788", "127.0.0.1", "9146"],
  ["b32f4c08-8d53-5fed-8034-4bfb144dfe10"],
  ["b32f4c08-8d53-5fed-8034-4bfb144dfe10"]
]

const output = input.map(([firstElement])=>[firstElement])

console.log(output)
```

a little more complicated for storing nth variable

```js
const input = [
  ["cfdb9868-0f69-5781-b1e4-793301280788", "127.0.0.1", "9146"],
  ["cfdb9868-0f69-5781-b1e4-793301280788", "127.0.0.1", "9146"],
  ["b32f4c08-8d53-5fed-8034-4bfb144dfe10"],
  ["b32f4c08-8d53-5fed-8034-4bfb144dfe10"]
]

const output = (n) => input.map((element)=> element[n] ? [element[n]] : [])

console.log("0", JSON.stringify(output(0)))
console.log("1", JSON.stringify(output(1)))
console.log("2", JSON.stringify(output(2)))
```

Assuming that you may not want to leave empty arrays if no element with given index exists you could modify the code above like so:

```js
const input = [
  ["cfdb9868-0f69-5781-b1e4-793301280788", "127.0.0.1", "9146"],
  ["cfdb9868-0f69-5781-b1e4-793301280788", "127.0.0.1", "9146"],
  ["b32f4c08-8d53-5fed-8034-4bfb144dfe10"],
  ["b32f4c08-8d53-5fed-8034-4bfb144dfe10"]
]

const output = (n) => input.reduce((list, element)=> element[n] ? [...list, element[n]] : list, [])

console.log("0", JSON.stringify(output(0)))
console.log("1", JSON.stringify(output(1)))
console.log("2", JSON.stringify(output(2)))
```

Comment: Imagine If I want to store second one or third one like first one What should I do ?

Comment: It is fantastic , but If is it possible don't show [ ] the empty bucket , How is it ?